# SMO Column.Default returns an empty string even though the column has a default value

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, t-sql, smo

I have a table with a column defined as

```
create table foo
(
   edit_date datetime default (getdate()) not null
)
```

Yet the `Default` property on the corresponding `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column` object is empty.

All of the other properties (e.g. `Name`, `DateType`, `InPrimaryKey`, etc) are correct.

The documentation is a bit sparse so I'm wondering whether or not that property is even meant to be read.

Should the `Column.Default` property be empty even when the column definition contains a default?

Answer (score 2):

The default value on a column is held as contrainst against the column itself. If you want to get at the value then use the DefaultContrainst property. Under that you can then use the Text property to get the actual value.

```
DefaultConstraint constraint = column.DefaultConstraint;
string value = Constraint.Text;
```